# Mongodb: How to load 'pages' of field of type array from the end of the array until its beginning

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination, infinite-scroll, mern

I am displaying messages in infinite scroll. In other words, I load set by set and display them using this function:

```
const getXNumberOfMessages = async (
  user_id,
  conv_id,
  page,
  results_per_page
) => {
  results_per_page = parseInt(results_per_page);

  const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
    _id: conv_id,
    members: { $in: [user_id] },
  }).populate({
    path: "messages",
    options: {
      skip: results_per_page * page,
      limit: results_per_page,
      
    },
  });
  let messages = conversation.messages.map((message) => {
    message.text = encryptionServices.decryptPrivateMessage(message.text);
    return message;
  });
  return messages;
};
```

The problem is that messages as you know get loaded from the **last set** until the **first set**.
Whereas that function does the opposite.
It load the the messages from the **first set** until the **last set**.
Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this like this:

```
const getXNumberOfMessages = async (
  user_id,
  conv_id,
  page,
  results_per_page
) => {
  results_per_page = parseInt(results_per_page);

  const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
    _id: conv_id,
    members: { $in: [user_id] },
  }).populate({
    path: "messages",
    options: {
      skip: results_per_page * page,
      limit: results_per_page,
      sort: { date: -1 },
    },
  });
  let messages = conversation.messages.map((message) => {
    message.text = encryptionServices.decryptPrivateMessage(message.text);
    return message;
  });
  messages.reverse();
  return messages;
};
```